# Move selection clippboard to the primary when new content arrives

Tags: linux, x11, clipboard

I'm not sure if its even possible, but do you know a way of moving the content of the selection clipboard to the primary, to use as a backup, when a new content arrives on the selection one?

The operation would be like this:

1. Move "MyText" to the selection clipboard
2. Move "MyTextV2" to the selection clipboard. *In this moment the "MyText" would be moved to the primary clippboard*
3. Move  "MyTextV3" to the selection clipboard. *In this moment the "MyTextV2" would be moved to the primary clipboard*

I imagine that this would be useful as a form of backup of the previous selection. Do you know a way of achieving that on Linux?